# Make a custom view that has multiple view as childs with a rounded corner border

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to design a custom layout like below:

[image]

So far I have done as following image but that's not exactly like the intended one:

[image]

Here is the code that I have tried.

***et_rounded_corner*******

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
     <corners android:radius="10dp" />
     <padding
          android:left="0dp"
          android:top="0dp"
          android:right="0dp"
          android:bottom="0dp"    >
     </padding>
     <stroke
          android:width="0dp"
          android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/et_rounded_corner"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/et_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"          
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Small"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste your current-tried layout codes to be able to help you or fix it.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท i have edited the post.Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I have fixed it by using the following background with imageview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"    >
    </padding>
    <stroke
        android:width="0dp"
        android:color="@color/red"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase your corner `radius` to a big number, like 100dp.

```
<corners android:radius="100dp" />
```

Android will then create a circle at each end for you.

---

Apply the same trick to a red background of your `ImageView~ and make the actual image have a transparent background. That will give you the correct rounded corners on the right of the red. But the left will now be rounded.

To make the left border of the red button vertical, either overlay a white block, or better, add a negative left padding to this new red background drawable. Then the left rounded part will try to draw outside the view, so it will not show.

---

As stated by other answer, you also need to remove the `padding` from the enclosing view, because this is adding the vertical space, and the right padding on the red image.

For the same reason, remove the padding on your image.

Comment: I have tried that before and that's the result.!(https://imgur.com/a/2Uokf7d). @Richard

Comment: @Shomen updated answer, add a red rounded background drawable to the red part, with a negative left padding.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but i have found a much easier solution.I have added it as an answer, you can check and suggest me if you want. @Richard Le Mesurier